# Adapter for std streams

Tags: c++, stl, std, iostream, streambuf

I have an abstract class in my project, its derivatives is used for input/output to different locations. 
It has virtual methods *read* and *write*.

```
virtual unsigned read(void *buf, unsigned len) = 0;
virtual void write(const void *buf, unsigned len) = 0;
```

I need a kind of an **adapter** between std streams (std::istream and std::ostream) and this class to redirect input/output to these methods.

So, for example, if

```
mystream << "some output";
```

is called, it will call the *write* method.

I guess i should overload *std::istream* and *std::ostream* or *std::streambuf*, but not sure  which methods.

What is the better way to implement this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [overloading '<<' with inhertiance and polymorphism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905648/overloading-with-inhertiance-and-polymorphism)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of *simple* but not *flexible* ways of doing it. Most of these solution will not leverage `istream` or `ostream`. For instance, overloading the `<<` operator is one way. The drawback is that you will have to implement this operator for all the usual types, and for all the standard manipulators, and so on. It may become a great burden.

This is sad because the whole thing about `istream` and `ostream` is only to *parse* and *format* not to do input or output. The *I/O* responsibility is given to the `streambuf`. And your task calls for a custom implementation of `streambuf` which uses your `read` and `write` methods.

The discussion is too long for such a small format as a stackoverflow answer but you can find good pointers in the following references.

**References**

- http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/beginners_guide_streambuf
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf
- [http://www.amazon.com/Standard-Library-Tutorial-Reference-2nd/dp/0321623215/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1442329302&sr=8-1&keywords=josuttis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321623215) , this book contains a chapter dedicated to streambuf implementation.

**Note**

As advised, using boost.iostreams maybe a good fit, but I don't know it enough.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, custom implementation of `streambuf` is exactly what i needed. The book of yours turned out pretty helpful well-explaining how `streambuf` works.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [boost iostreams library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html). It provides a framework that makes it easier to define iostreams with custom sources and sinks (input and output devices).

Answer (score 0):

I am a fan of std::stringstream, and perhaps your class could make use of it.

```
std::stringstream ss;

ss << "some output";
```

from which something would invoke write like:

```
write(ss.str().c_str(),  ss.str().size());
```

You will have to figure out how to connect the two, but this has the advantage of providing all stream io.

On the other hand, directly implementing operator << and >>  is not too difficult.

> I guess i should overload std::istream and std::ostream or
>   std::streambuf, but not sure which methods.

Start with the method you need first, then add functionality as you identify the requirements.